# What SQL Query will be useful on this? ( ORACLE)

Tags: sql, scripting, sql-scripts

I want to get the value of column and set it to the other column but this is the challenge to me.

Both are in the same table

```
DATA 1               DATA  2

Prev.No = 789        App.No = 789
UserRefNo. = 23      RenewdNo = ?
```

Question is: what query will I use to set the `RenewdNo` of Data 2 from the `UserRefNo` of data 1?

There will be a lot of rows to update.

Expected results:

```
  Data 2 

  App.No = 789
  RenewdNo = 23
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You need an update query like:

```
Update d2
set d2.RenewdNo = d.UserRefNo
from Data2 d2
inner join Data1 d on d.Prev_no=d2.Appno
```

Comment: you can use column from * FROM *? because they are on the same table

Comment: Update (select query)
set d2.RenewdNo = d.UserRefNo
from  (select)
inner join Data1 d on d.Prev_no=d2.Prev_no

how about this?i try to manage multiple

Comment: Do not use "select" keywords here please

Comment: Surely that join is wrong... Should be `inner join Data1 d on d.Prev_no=d2.App_no`

Comment: btw im using oracle?